# Queries executing slow with tinkerpop Java api

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

Using tinkerpop Java API for queries with Titan , Cassandra as storage and Elastic as the query index. Works fine with the gremlin console.  Any pointers on what to look for ? ( The data or the query size does not matter , seen with no data and minimal query as well . Can rule out caching too.)

Comment: How much slower are they in your application as compared to the console? and you wrote Titan, do you mean JanusGraph?

Comment: Watch out for network latency between the application and Cassandra. Benchmark your Cassandra cluster. Use local SSD rather than network storage.

Comment: @stephen they are about 8-10 times slower. I mean Titan , not JanusGraph. Is there a way to **not** use ScriptEngine.eval for evaluating the query when you are running the queries from a java application.

Comment: @Jason Thanks. Will keep those points in mind. However I am looking for a way to run the queries instead of using ScriptEngine.eval. Do you know of a way to do it ?

Comment: Gremlin is just Java - just write Java. You don't need to evaluate Gremlin strings in the scriptengine. If you evaluate them in the scriptengine they will incur an initial compilation cost (future executions will be fast) - discussion here:  https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gremlin-users/p2zaThRppC4/QlxoAtUWDwAJ

Comment: uh...just occurred to me that if you are using Titan you might be using a really old version for some reason (in which case my advice may not apply so well)...what version were you using?

Comment: @stephenmallette 3.2.0

Comment: @stephenmallette i saw the groups discussion , but not clear what the alternative to using scriptinengine is when you want to embed the query in a java app. can you please clarify.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're missing. `Graph graph = TitanFactory.open(); g = graph.traversal(); List<Vertex> vertices = g.V().toList()` - it's just Java. You don't need a scriptengine to evaluate that code.

Comment: hm , ok. I will try. Suppose i take the query as an argument , i am guessing i could do List<Vertex> v = q // where q is any arbitrary query input by the user of any length.

Comment: if you are dynamically evaluating code input from a textbox by a user that you hold as a string, then you need the scriptengine. that wasn't clear from this question and the comments you've posted. if you are the same person as the one asking that question on the gremlin-users mailing list then my answers over there stand - i didn't connect that this was the same question I guess. also, i would highly recommend upgrading past 3.2.0 - that's really really old stuff.

Comment: right, thats what i figured and hence my question about scriptengine alternatives. Should have made that clear. Thank you again.